# Changing the Style of a HTML-Button within a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am trying to change the style class of a button when clicking it but it is not working how it should.

I need the style/icon change inside a JS function because I am doing some more stuff when the buttons gets clicked.

```js
function generate() {
//// Some stuff
  document.getElementById('btn1').class = 'play icon fa fa-stop';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 

<div class='container20'>
  <button class='play icon fa fa-play-circle-o' type='button' onclick='generate()' id="btn1">Button</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `class` not exist, there is `className`, so replace it by `className`
- In onclick there is function so, you need to add `()` in it so, replace `generate` to `generate()`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<div class='container20'>
    <button class = 'play icon fa fa-play-circle-o' type = 'button' onclick = 'generate()' id = "btn1">Button</button>     
</div>                      
<div class='container80'>
    <script>            
        function generate() {
            //// Some stuff
            document.getElementById('btn1').className = 'play icon fa fa-stop';
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: glad to help you bro

Answer (score 1):

Use `className` and not `class`

```
document.getElementById('btn1').className = 'play icon fa-stop';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Below code will add the 3 classes to any existing classes already applied to the button

```
document.getElementById('btn1').classList.add('play', 'icon', 'fa-stop');
```

Below code will replace any existing classes already added to the button with play, icon and fa-stop

```
document.getElementById('btn1').className = 'play icon fa-stop';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting `className`, and having to preserve the `play icon` parts of the className text, you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to remove and add the necessary classes

```
function generate() {
    const b = document.getElementById('btn1')
    b.classList.remove('fa-play-circle-o`);
    b.classList.add('fa-stop');
}
```

Yes, it's more lines, but it's more flexible too. For example you could write a method that takes the old class and the new class and call it from anywhere.

```
function changeClass(element, old, new) {
    element.classList.remove(old);
    element.classList.add(new);
}
```

Also, since you are running in an event handler, you don't have to `getElementById('btn1')` because the event.*target* is the button that was clicked.
This (below) *attaches* an event handler, rather than using an inline `onclick=`, and I've added background color just so the effect of clicking the button can be seen.

```js
document.getElementById('btn1')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.target.classList.remove('fa-play-circle-o');
            e.target.classList.add('fa-stop');
        });
```

```css
button {
    font-weight: bold;
}
button.fa-play-circle-o {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}
button.fa-stop {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container20">
  <button id="btn1" type="button"
          class="play icon fa-play-circle-o">Button</button> 
</div>
```